Trying to connect SQL Server database in Metabase
I am trying to connect my SQL Server DB in Metabase. I am using SQL server authentication.I am running the metabase locally. I entered the details as follows:
Host: 127.0.0.1
DB: Practice_DB
DB instance name:MSSQLSERVER (tried with and without it)
and my user credentials for the server. However, i am getting timeout after 10 secs.
The second thing i was trying with different port than the standard port.
I used this query to check server is listening to which port
USE master
GO
Xp_readerrorlog
According to this, it was
Server is listening on [ ::1  1434].
Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1  1434].
I used the port 1434. This time, i am getting this The TCP/IP connection to the host 127.0.0.1, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: no further information. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
I have enabled the TCP protocol in the sql server configuration manager. However. i am unable to restart the sql server service SQL server service error
What should i do to connect sql DB with it. Also, i am not sure about the DB instance and tried using the SQL Server instance name FROM service

You probably don't want to be connecting to tcp/1434. That's the Diagnostic Administrator Connection and only allows a single connection at a time to 127.0.0.1:1434 from a member of the sysadmin role.

Given the start error it seems like you could have modified the Domain/Windows account under which the SQL Server service was meant to execute while investigating with SQL Server Configuration Manager.

This is a corporate environment so they might have modified the domain/Windows account. So should i  use the port 1433? And what else i can do

You need to use the port 1433.
Make sure you have a inbound rule for 1433 to allow connection.

Open Windows Firewall with Advanced Security.
Add a new inbound rule for port 1433 to allow connections.

